# How a step value for the function range() step?

Tags: python

I have the following function in python.

I aim to generate iperf traffic that increases from 1 until the function `check_overload()` returns other values except 0. Then, I calculate `overload_point_A`. After all, I go to #Step. II in which the traffic is being sent continuously with the same value of the overload point.

```py
    #######
    # Step. I
    #######
count = 10000
r = range(1, count)
    for bandwidth in r:
        print "============"
        print ("bandwidth = "+str(bandwidth))
        check = check_overload(SegmentPath, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4, step, capacity)
        for overload_point_A in check:
            if overload_point_A == 0:
                print (color.RED + "functionA: iperf " + str(bandwidth)+""+color.END)
                break    
            else:
                print "Overload Point I. = ", overload_point_A
                del r[bandwidth:]
                time.sleep(sleepTime)
                break

    #######
    # Step. II
    #######
    print("Overloaded of Tunnel 4 at " + str(overload_point_A) + " kbps.")
    isrunninga = 0
    bandwidth = overload_point_A
    while True:
        print("Continuous Phase I. bandwidth = "+ str(bandwidth)+" Mbps")
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        if isrunninga == 1 :
            bandwidth = bandwidth + 1
```

The problem I am facing is that, when I modify `r = range(1, count)` and add a integer range() step value `r = range(1, count, step)`, the function runs only the Step, is there any way to fix it?

Here is the output I got without putting a step for `range()` function:

```py
...
..
======
bandwidth = 7
Link is not overloaded
load =  12.0  <  20 - 2 *  3  =  14
functionA: iperf 7
============
bandwidth = 8
Link is not overloaded
load =  12.0  <  20 - 2 *  3  =  14
functionA: iperf 8
============
bandwidth = 9
Link is overloaded
Overload Point I. =  14.0
Overloaded of Tunnel 4 at 14.0 kbps.
Continuous Phase I. bandwidth = 14.0 Mbps
```

And here is the output I got with putting a step = 3 for `range()` function:

```py
...
..
bandwidth = 13
Link is not overloaded
load =  4.0  <  20 - 2 *  3  =  14
functionA: iperf 13
============
bandwidth = 16
Link is not overloaded
load =  11.0  <  20 - 2 *  3  =  14
functionA: iperf 16
============
bandwidth = 19
Link is not overloaded
load =  11.0  <  20 - 2 *  3  =  14
functionA: iperf 19
============
bandwidth = 22
Link is not overloaded
load =  11.0  <  20 - 2 *  3  =  14
functionA: iperf 22
============
bandwidth = 25
Link is overloaded
Overload Point I. =  13.0
============
bandwidth = 28
Link is overloaded
Overload Point I. =  13.0
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal range() step value"?

Comment: What do you mean by “the function only runs the Step”? 1 or 2?

Comment: @Sayse sorry I meant integer value. `r = range(1, count, step)` and let's say `step = 3`

Comment: @dijksterhuis only Step.I if there's no step value in `range()` function. like this `r = range(1, count)`

Comment: So, it runs for every third value, starting from 1; that seems fine. What do you exactly want it do?

Comment: I think he wants to break out of the range for loop once the   else statement has been encountered. Is that right @TimLuka ?

Comment: @00 well, it does not run properly when I use `r = range(1, count, step)` It should give the same output as the 1st I have shown but with considering the `step` value in `range()`

Comment: @dijksterhuis exactly, as the 1st output shows, but with the step value in range()

Comment: Seems like when “Overload Point I.” is printed, the second part of the code should be run?

Comment: This question is unclear: the actual question is hidden in the comments, and the code has some bad indentation, which actually is relevant to the question: which loop (inner or outer) is it the intention to break out of in the first place. Fix the code properly first, so that it is reproduce. We also don't see what's going on in `check_overload`, yet somehow magically, there is output that says "Link is (not) overloaded".

Comment: @00 I think the while loop indentation is meant to be like that. Why else would they try to delete the remainder of the range and then break out? They’re trying to break out of both for loops to get to the while loop. But I agree, the question is very unclear.

Comment: @dijksterhuis but the first indentation is incorrect, and for me, that makes it less clear whether the break is intended for the inner loop (it only works there anyway), or otherwise.

Comment: What's even weirder: the if-else both have breaks, so the (inner) for loop always get broken out *immediately* upon the first iteration of the `for overload_point_A in check`: loop. I actually think that is your problem.

Comment: @00 ah sorry yes the `r = range...` bit, gotcha. Yeah on the breaks, I think refactor the while loop into a function and move it into the else clause. But I’m still unclear on if the for loops should all break if it’s called. Reads like @TimLuka wants a GOTO statement in his code.